# Android - How to make app autorun in background daily to fetch data from internet?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I am developing a web crawler using Android. Currently my crawler crawls the web using asynctask every time the app starts, which takes a long time.

I want my app to update its database daily in the background, without needing to launch the MainActivity interface.
After doing some research, I found the following classes can help me:

1. Service
2. AlarmManager

Can someone shed some light for me, I'm new to Android programming.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should read this chapter: https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

You need an alarm manager to run the service every hour. You also need to receive a broadcast when the device reboots to start the alarm manager...

This can also help you: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Comment: so do I need to call the service somewhere in the MainActivity? or Android does it automatically from the appmanifest?

Comment: You need to start it from the main activity and from the class referenced in the broadcast receiver related to "OnBootComplet" event

Answer (score 1):

Below are some ways that you can go about doing job scheduling:

- [Android JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) -  Minimum API: 21
- [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) -    Minimum API: 9
- [evernote/android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)    - Minimum API: 14

You can schedule it to run every X hours with other params like run when internet comes, battery should be above critical level. Check them out and make a decision according to your requirements.